# What is Complexity of a program and how to calculate it?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I am a Java Developer, I wanted to know about Complexity of Program and its calculation ? (i am beginner please answer in simple terms that i can understand 
thanks in advance..!!)

Comment: Try these as a basic explanation: https://justin.abrah.ms/computer-science/big-o-notation-explained.html https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Comment: To find information about time-complexity, click on the time-complexity tag, then click *"about »"* at the upper right, under the number.

Comment: This is probably not the right forum for this questionm as it is very broad and complex. I recommend checking out a few written resources on the matter. Myself, I learnt it [from here](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=khan+academy+time+complexity)

Comment: Did you *try* a web search??? E.g. google [`Complexity of Program`](https://www.google.com/search?q=Complexity+of+Program)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally complexity is a number of operation you have to perform to achieve your goal.

Complexity is marked as O(n) where `n` is the complexity. For example complexity of assignment is O(1).

Complexity of access to array element is O(1) too. Complexity of iteration over all elements of array, collection, map etc is O(n) where n is number of elements of the collection. For example if you want to find sum of all elements of n-elements array you have to perform operation with complexity O(n).

Please note that complexity of looking for specific element of array is n also although average number of operations is n/2 because the element may be at first, last or any other position.

Complexity of sorting depends on the algorithm. Simple algorithms sort arrays with complexity of O(n^2), while better algorithms like quick short have O(n*ln(n)).

Comment: Quick sort doesn't have ln(n) complexity.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Formal_analysis

Comment: @AndyTurner, sure, thanks, fixed. It is n*ln(n)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of complexity
1. space complexity
2. Time complexity

The time required for the execution of a program(or loops or statement) is reffered to as time complexity. The space or memory required for the program is reffered to as space complexity. Both complexities are measured in Big Oh notations .